# Login system using physical postgres users not "logical" users

Tags: security, postgresql, authentication, database-design, auditing

I'm currently building an application that has to conform with SOX auditing requirements. One of these, is that all inserts, updates and deletes (but delete you can ignore), need to leave a trail that is difficult, if not impossible for a standard user (or non-DBA) to change.

This means, I need to enforce the auditing at the database level via triggers on insert, update and delete.

My problem is; this is a webapp... The typical design pattern is to store users as "logical", for example; in a "users" table. What I need, is for the application to actually run as the logged in user after the initial login.

My thinking (which is likely not the best) is to do the following:

1. Load the login page via a standard username (webapp)
2. Check a table called "stored_users" for their logical username/password.
3. If they enter the correct user/pass; retrieve the db username, generate a session password (stored in KVSession on redis), update the user on the postgres DB and login with it.
4. After a defined time of inactivity, destroy the password session, reset the db password for the user and log them out.

Does this sound like a safe way to ensure the following?

1. My users are always using postgres users; so I can enforce the triggers via CURRENT_USER etc..
2. Security by always regenerating the postgres user password with a random, temporary password

I'd really like to hear what others have to say on this matter; as I really can't find this on Google (or I'm not searching the right terms). It seems the prevailing mindset for user logins is to store them as logical records and have a global connection user.

Comment: Why not use 2 users? One superuser, that sets up and control logging (and other superuser stuff) and other one, that uses the tables without the ability to disable triggers (just forbid all ddl, and dml on logging tables)

Comment: @IgorRomanchenko - unfortunately, that would just mean the triggers create the audit records with the subusername, which doesn't help show "who" did what. Under this scenario, updated_by and created_by would be "limited_user" for example, rather than "johndoe". Keep in mind, the triggers use CURRENT_USER to prevent someone trying to force a new value in. The trigger looks at CURRENT_USER and NEW.[audit_columns] to figure out if CURRENT_USER != NEW.values - this is the best way to prevent someone trying to inject a forged user.

Comment: Just create a table that associates `pg_backend_pid()` (pid of current user session) with logical user when the user logs in. With such table and `pg_backend_pid()` you will be able to get current logical user for all checks in triggers.

Comment: Also such table can be used to log successful/failed login attempts and login/logoff time.

Comment: So in the triggers, instead of looking at current_user, I would have to run a select on an association table to look for the username for pid(x) and then check if new.user != user_from_pid_assoc_table? Sounds like a reasonable solution. Less server maintenance as well I guess (settings up users etc). However, this doesn't seem to solve the solution of someone jumping into the shell and running updates/inserts, in fact, the triggers then will simply fail. Direct DB Access may still be required for some staff, and they mustn't be able to modify this type of data either.

Comment: You can use the same secure PL/SQL functions, that are used in normal login from app. Some instructions like: 1) Log in under common user 2) Execute `login_function('login','pass')` to create logical user association. Or automate this 2 steps with a simple shell script.

Comment: Added benefit - without such logical user association triggers will deny any changes to data, making the common user (without proper logical user) effectively Read only.

Comment: @IgorRomanchenko - you're right. Could you please draft up your comments as an answer so I can accept it and award the points. This is a fantastic way to go about what I was trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve your goal

> all inserts, updates and deletes, need to leave a trail that is
>   difficult, if not impossible for a standard user to change.

you can create:

1) Two schemas: one for common tables, one for security stuff like login/pass(hash) table, user session log, change log table, etc.

2) Two users: one common user, that can only use dml on common schema (no ddl), one superuser.

3) Login function that will check provided user/pass against login/pass table and log successful/failed attempts into user session log (you need `SECURITY DEFINER` function)

4) Set of audit triggers on common schema tables that will check the user privileges and log any changes, made by the user (`SECURITY DEFINER` functions here too).